# Why is graphql-dotnet returning "Expected non-null value" error for this schema?

Tags: c#, graphql, graphql-dotnet

I have a simple schema that I'm trying to query as follows:

```
{
  subQuery {
    subObjectGraph {
      Name
    }
  }
}
```

But "graphiql" throws the following error, without even seeming to run my query.

```
{
  "errors": [
    {
      "message": "Expected non-null value, resolve delegate return null for \"$Api.Schema.Queries.MySubObjectGraphType\"",
      "extensions": {
        "code": "INVALID_OPERATION"
      }
    }
  ]
}
```

What is wrong with my schema (below)? I am new-ing up a SubObject, so I don't understand why the error message implies the value is null.

```
    public class Schema: GraphQL.Types.Schema
    {
        public Schema(IDependencyResolver resolver): base(resolver)
        {
            Query = resolver.Resolve<RootQuery>();  
            Mutation = null;
        }
    }

    public class RootQuery: ObjectGraphType
    {
        public RootQuery(IDependencyResolver resolver)
        {
            Name = "Query";

            Field<MySubQuery>(
                name: "subQuery",
                resolve: ctx => resolver.Resolve<MySubQuery>());
        }
    }


    public class MySubQuery: ObjectGraphType
    {
        public MySubQuery()
        {
            Name = "TempSubQuery";

            Field<StringGraphType>("SubQueryName", resolve: ctx => "Some string value");

            Field<MySubObjectGraphType>(
                name: "subObjectGraph",
                resolve: ctx => FetchFromRepo());
        }


        //Repo access would go here, but just new-ing the object for now.
        private SubObject FetchFromRepo()
        {
            return new SubObject() { Name = "some sub object" };
        }
    }


    public class SubObject
    {
        public string Name { get; set; }
    }

    public class MySubObjectGraphType: ObjectGraphType<SubObject>
    {
        public MySubObjectGraphType()
        {
            Name = "MySubObject";
            Description = "An object with leaf nodes";

            Field(l => l.Name);
        }
    }
```

The code works fine if I substitute MySubObjectGraphType with StringGraphType, so the problem must be with configuration of MySubObjectGraphType.

Please help? I'm using v2.4.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

You need to add a service registration for the `MySubObjectGraphType` in your `Startup.cs`

So the rule could be described as "custom types deriving from `ObjectGraphType` must be registered via dependency injection at some point"

e.g in `Startup.cs`:

`services.AddSingleton<MySubObjectGraphType>();`

Answer (score 0):

You are returning a GraphType in subQuery in your RootQuery.  Resolvers should only return DTOs and never GraphTypes.

If you are trying to organize your queries, then just return an empty object.

```
Field<MySubQuery>(
  name: "subQuery",
  resolve: ctx => new {});
```

https://graphql-dotnet.github.io/docs/getting-started/query-organization

Comment: Thanks Joe, and thanks for a great library! I tried changing as you suggested, but I still get the exact same issue. Looks like something is wrong with MySubObjectGraphType, but I can't figure out what. The "FetchFromRepo" method returns a Dto, so I imagine it should map to the graphType without issues? Slightly updated gist over here: https://gist.github.com/willemodendaal/77ff0feded77a33238e43142c7a00f3f

Comment: I'm using v2.4 by the way.